# Problem with Bluetooth Audio

Tags: server, bluetooth

As I stuck after hours of work I hope someone here can help me solving my audio issues.

I bought an USB Bluetooth Dongle and a Bluetooth Sound Adapter.
I installed the bluez driver and bluez tools and added the device so it is now trusted etc (see results from `bt-device -i 00:10:61:12:xx:xx` ):

```
[00:10:61:12:xx:xx]
  Name: GT BT-Receiver 21
  Alias: GT BT-Receiver 21 [rw]
  Address: 00:10:61:12:xx:xx
  Icon: audio-card
  Class: 0x240414
  Paired: 1
  Trusted: 1 [rw]
  Blocked: 0 [rw]
  Connected: 1
  UUIDs: [AudioSink, AVRemoteControlTarget, AVRemoteControl]
```

Now I am trying to add this as my `pulseaudio` standard device to play sound from commandline.

At least this is not working at all.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What issues are you having, what devices make and models are you using, what have you tried.....

Answer (score 0):

ALSO PROVIDE WHICH DISTRO AND RELEASE ARE YOU RUNNIG

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothAudio

Answer (score 0):

The number 1 issue I have seen with Ubuntu and bluetooth audio is that one module is not loaded, so
`sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`

Then delete the pairing and pair with your audio device again and see if it is in sound settings.  Some versions of blueman have a bug that will remove the module-bluetooth-discover and you will have to manually load it after every reboot